# Qt Signal not making it to the slot until mouserelease

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I am having a problem where I emit a signal in a mouseMove event, but that signal does not get recieved by a slot on another object until i release the mouse.

Details:
I have a class called `SelectableItem`, which subclasses `QGraphicsObject` :

```
#pragma once
#if !defined PARTS_SELECTABLE_ITEM_H
#define PARTS_SELECTABLE_ITEM_H

#include <QGraphicsObject>

namespace Parts {
class SelectableItem : public QGraphicsObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SelectableItem();

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) = 0;
    QRectF boundingRect() const = 0;

    void SetIsSelectedCustom(bool b);
    bool IsSelectedCustom();

    void SetIsSelectable(bool b);
    bool IsSelectable();

    void SetIsHovering(bool b);
    bool IsHovering();

    void Move(QPointF offset);

signals:
    void moveItem(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e);
    void deselectAllItems();
    void deselectItem(Parts::SelectableItem*);
    void selectItem(Parts::SelectableItem*);
    void stopSelectionDrag();
    void stopMovingParts();
    void deleteSelectedItems();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e);
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e);
    void hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *e);
    void hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *e);

    bool m_is_selected;
    bool m_is_hovering;
    bool m_is_selectable;

}; // class SelectableItem
} // namespace Parts

#endif // PARTS_SELECTABLE_ITEM_H
```

I have two other classes that subclass the `SelectableItem` class. They are `Part` and `Terminal`

Part:

```
#pragma once
#if !defined PARTS_PART_H
#define PARTS_PART_H

#include "PartLabel.h"
#include "PartDialog.h"
#include "Terminal.h"
#include "SelectableItem.h"
#include <QGraphicsObject>
#include <QGraphicsSvgItem>
#include <QSvgRenderer>
#include <map>

namespace Parts {

class Terminal;
class Part : public SelectableItem {
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    friend class PartLabel;

    Part();
    ~Part();

    enum PartLabelLocation {
        North,
        South,
        East,
        West
    };

    // Inherited Functions
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    void setPos(qreal x, qreal y);

    // Part Functions
    void SetData(std::map<std::string, std::string> data);
    void SetTerminals(std::list<Terminal*> terms);
    void AddTerminalsToScene(QGraphicsScene* s);
    void SetPartGraphic(QGraphicsSvgItem *svg);
    void SetDialog(PartDialog *d);
    std::string GetName();
    void SetName(const std::string &name);
    void Move(QPointF offset);
    PartLabel* GetLabel();
    std::map<std::string, std::string>* GetData();
    std::list<Terminal*> GetTerminalList();
    QPointF GetCenterPointPos();

    void SetLabelNorth();
    void SetLabelSouth();
    void SetLabelEast();
    void SetLabelWest();
    void ResetLabelPosition();

    QGraphicsSvgItem* GetPartSvg();

signals:
    void partRotated();

private:

    // Inherited Functions
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e);
    void hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *e);
    void hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *e);
    void contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *e);

    // Part Functions
    void DrawTerminal(QPainter *painter, QPointF &point);
    QRectF CalculateBoundingBox();
    void Initialize();
    void RotateCW();
    void RotateCCW();
    void OpenPropertiesDialog();
    void SinglePartContextMenu(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *e);
    void MultiplePartContextMenu(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *e);

    // Part Members
    QGraphicsSvgItem *m_part_graphic;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m_data;
    std::list<Terminal*> m_terminals;
    QRectF m_bounding_box;
    PartLabel *m_label;
    PartDialog *m_dialog;

    bool m_is_initialized;

    int m_label_position;

}; // class Part
}; // namespace Parts

#endif // PARTS_PART_H
```

Terminal:

```
#pragma once
#if !defined PARTS_TERMINAL_H
#define PARTS_TERMINAL_H

#define TERMINAL_RADIUS 15
#define CONNECTED_TERMINAL_RADIUS 7.5

#include "Part.h"
#include "SelectableItem.h"
#include <QGraphicsObject>

namespace Parts {
class Part;
class Connection;
class Terminal : public SelectableItem {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum TerminalDirection {
        North,
        East,
        South,
        West
    };

    Terminal(const std::string &name, const QPointF &rel_coords, const std::string &direction);

    // Inherited Functions
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
    QRectF boundingRect() const;

    QPointF GetRelativeCoord();
    QPointF GetConnectionCoord();
    void SetPart(Part *p);
    bool HasPart();
    void Move();
    void RotateCW();
    void RotateCCW();
    void SetIsConnected(bool b);
    bool IsConnected();

    void AddConnection(Connection *c);
    void RemoveConnection(Connection *c);
    std::list<Connection*> GetConnectionList();

signals:
    void connectionBegun(Parts::Terminal *t);
    void connectionCompleted(Parts::Terminal *t);

private:
    // Inherited Functions
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e);
    void hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *e);
    void hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *e);
    //void contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *e);

    void IncrementDirection();
    void DecrementDirection();

    QPointF m_rel_coords;
    QPointF m_rotated_rel_coords;

    bool m_is_connected;

    int m_direction;
    int m_rotation_angle;

    QRectF m_bounding_rect;
    Part *m_part;
    std::string m_name;
    std::list<Connection*> m_connections;

}; // class Terminal
} // namespace Parts

#endif // PARTS_TERMINAL_H
```

The `SelectableItem` class's mouseMove function is as follows:

```
void SelectableItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e) {
    if(!m_is_selectable)
        return;

    if(m_is_selected)
        emit moveItem(e);
    else {
        emit deselectAllItems();
        emit selectItem(this);
    }
}
```

The signal `emit selectItem(this)` is instantly recieved by another class `SysGraphicsScene` which handles item selection.

The problem I'm having is that the `Part` class emits this signal via its base class and the signal is recieved by the `SysGraphicsScene` class instantly. However, the `Terminal` class emits this signal via it's base class (`SelectableItem`, which is the same base class that `Part` has.) and the signal is not recieved instantly by `SysGraphicsScene` but only after mouseReleased.

I have no idea why two derived classes would work differently. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh found the problem. Some of my `Terminal` objects were never getting connected to signals while som where. I knew it had to be something basic. :/